# Is composition of an absolutely continuous function and a $C^1$ function still absolutely continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, absolute-continuity

Suppose $y:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}^n$ is absolutely continuous, where $[a,b]\subset \mathbb{R}$ is a compact interval. Let $\phi:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ be a $C^1$ function. Is it true that $$\phi \circ y:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$$ is also absolutely continuous?

Can I have an hint  in order to prove/disprove it?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: since $y([a,b])$ is compact and connected, the restriction of $\varphi$ to $y([a,b])$ is Lipschitz.  What can you say about the composition $\psi \circ y$ if $\psi$ is Lipschitz?

Comment: Suppose $L>0$ is the Lipschitz constant  of $\psi$ on $y([a,b])$. Fix $\epsilon>0$. Since $y$ is AC then there exist $\delta>0$ s.t. for every finite collection of open disjoint intervals $\{(x_i,z_i)\}, i=1, \dots, n$ each one contained on $[a,b]$ one has $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \left\lVert x_i-z_i\right\rVert<\frac{\epsilon}{L}$. Got it! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just a question. Is the restriction of a $C^1$ function on a compact subset of the domain always Lipschitz continuous?

Comment: Good question.  I realized my argument that the restriction of $\varphi$ to $y([a,b])$ is Lipschitz also uses the fact that $y([a,b])$ is connected, because I was using the Mean Value Theorem.  I’ve edited accordingly.  In general, restricting a $C^1$ function to a compact, connected set gives a Lipschitz function.

Comment: Thank you so much Jordan, really appreciated!